# Getting 404 not found error for using Middleware with router.post method in Expressjs, why?

Tags: reactjs, api, express, middleware, router

** Express**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
const app = express();
const checkUrl = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("current route is: ", req.originalUrl);
    next();
}
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello Express ");
});
```

** For this Endpoint I am adding Middleware, but I am getting 404 not found while hitting

```
  router.post('/login', checkUrl, function (req, res) {
        console.log("yes")
        res.send("Hello Express Login ");
    })
    app.use('/', checkUrl);
    app.listen(8000, () => console.log("App is listening at port"));
```

Comment: I can see you're calling the middleware twice , application level and route level .that could cause a problem. Try either omitting the app.use or the checkUrl in the post

Comment: Another thing that could be the problem you are not doing `app.use('/path',router)`